# Amlogic Android 9.0 navigation issue by remote control

Tags: navigation, frameworks, android-9.0-pie, remote-control

In Android 9.0 AmLogic Boxes, there's probably a framework issue with certain apps like Cyberflix, Beetv related with IR remote.
User cannot go up to use the menu, but only need a mouse to access them.

I can show the main Activity's layout file here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff303030"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff303030"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/CyberFlix_Theme_AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/CyberFlix_Theme_AppBarOverlay">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_spinner_home"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llFooterHome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ViewStub
                    android:id="@+id/castMiniControllerContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout="@layout/cast_mini_controller_fragment"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/adViewMain"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.cybermedia.cyberflix.ui.widget.AutofitSuperRecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvTvShowList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/llFooterHome"
                android:columnWidth="@dimen/image_poster_width"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                app:layout_empty="@layout/view_empty"
                app:layout_moreProgress="@layout/view_more"
                app:mainLayoutId="@layout/layout_recyclerview_verticalscroll"
                app:recyclerClipToPadding="false"
                app:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#ff303030"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_home_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Is there anyone can help to figure out the reason and proper solution for this issue?
Thanks